# How do I create a transformation matrix from a polynomial transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$T(p(x))=\int_{0}^{1} p(x) d x.$$

(a) Show $T$ is a linear transformation.

(b) Compute $\mathcal{N}(T) .$ Is $T$ one-to-one?

(c) Show that $T$ is onto.

(d) Let $B$ be the standard basis for $\mathcal{P}_{2}$ and let $B^{\prime}=\{1\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}$. Find $[T]_{B}^{B^{\prime}}$.

(e) Use the matrix found in part (d) to compute $T\left(-x^{2}-3 x+2\right)$.

---

I was able to prove it was a linear transformation, but computing the null space has been a challenge. Typically with these problems I would create a transformation matrix based on the linear transformation, but since it is a polynomial I can't seem to create one in order to solve for the null space. [Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzpLU.jpg).

Comment: Let $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$. Then $\int_0^1p(x)dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k dx=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{k+1}$. So, $N(T)$ is the set of polynomials such that the above sum becomes 0. Since the set clearly consists of more than one element, T is not one-to-one. Since the sum can take an arbitrary real number if you take an arbitrary polynomial, T is onto.

Answer (score 1):

(b) As explained in the comment above,

$$ \ker T = \left\{ a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2}x^2 \in \mathbb{R}_{2}[x] : a_{0} + \frac{a_{1}}{2} + \frac{a_{2}}{3} = 0  \right\} $$

We see, for instance, that $1 + x - \frac{9}{2}x^{2} \in \ker T$, so $T$ is not injective.

(c) To see that $T$ is onto, let $r \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary and consider the constant polynomial $p(x) = r$. Then $Tp = r$.

(d) To find $[T]_{B}^{B'}$, we take the basis $1, x, x^{2}$ and evaluate $T$ at each of these polynomials. We then get $1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}$, so

$$[T]_{B}^{B'} = \left(1 \hspace{0.5cm} \frac{1}{2} \hspace{0.5cm} \frac{1}{3} \right).$$

(e) Finally, $T( -x^{2} -3x + 2) = -T(x^{2}) -3T(x) + 2T(1) = -\frac{1}{3} - \frac{3}{2} + 2 = \frac{1}{6}.$